# Why my example is passing test without model validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I've got the following model and test file. To my understanding, the last example should fail until I validate the `body` attribute in the model but it's passing the test. I'm not sure what it is that I'm missing. Any assistance is highly appreciated in advance, thanks.

`article.rb`

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 6..25 }
end
```

`article_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Article, type: :model do
  subject { Article.new(title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet ', body: 'consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, labore?') }
  before { subject.save }

  it 'is not valid without a title' do
    subject.title = nil
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end

  it 'is not valid if the title is too short' do
    subject.title = 'a'
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end

  it 'is not valid if the title is too long' do
    subject.title = 'a' * 26
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end

  it 'is not valid without a body' do
    subject.body = nil
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: don't see any validation on the body attribute.

Comment: @dbugger That's correct, shouldn't the test fail and then pass after providing validation?
If I'm not mistaken In TDD one rights the test first which fails and then the validation for the test to pass. The first three tests failed and then passed after I provided the validation, I expected the fourth one to behave the same if I'm not missing something.

Comment: @AlphyGacheru the test passes because your default title is not valid. Your title validation requires the length to be between 6 and 25 characters but your default title is 28 characters long so the model is invalid. It has nothing to do with the `body` being present or not.

Comment: @engineersmnky, thank you. Now I understand. It failed as expected by not having the `body` validation and reducing the `title` characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the validation for the body attribute.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 6..25 }
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

Comment: That's correct, shouldn't the test fail and then pass after providing validation? If I'm not mistaken In TDD one rights the test first which fails and then the validation for the test to pass. The first three tests failed and then passed after I provided the validation, I expected the fourth one to behave the same if I'm not missing something

Comment: Yep you are right. But in rails works 'convention over configuration' and there not any validations in models by default.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. The last example passes the test with or without the `body validation` in the `model`. If that's the expected behavior would you kindly elaborate on it?